# What happens when you use a name tag on a strange weapon?

Tags: team-fortress-2

If I use a name tag on a strange weapon in Team Fortress 2, does it keep the kill count and name changes? So that it becomes "strange description"+"name"

Or does the name tag over write the name changing properties so that it will always be what you name it? So that it is always "name"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [TF2 Wiki...](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Strange_items#Strange_items)

> The Strange quality was introduced alongside the Über update, available through unboxing a series 19 and onward crate. They have a kill count that shows the total amount of kills obtained with the weapon. The items will have their default name changed dependent on how many kills the weapon has. For instance, after getting ten kills the weapon will change from 'Strange' to 'Unremarkable'. Renaming a Strange weapon hides its prefix, even if it levels up after that.

It appears that it will keep the kill count, the name will simply stop updating.

Comment: Don't know why this hit the front page, but it did, so I'll chime in here.  It doesn't entirely hid the name.  My flamethrower, "Ink Spots" lists the name in orange, and underneath that says "Spectacularly Lethal Flamethrower - Kills: 353" in a darker grey.  It still shows the strange name, just not on the main line.